# How do I update state object when an event is emitted from an outside component using ngrx with Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I have a footer component with a "Save" button that is always visible in my Angular 6 app - it is a core component that never destroys unless the app is destroyed.  Each page of the app is a different section in saving a Product, so for example a "General Info" section, "Pricing" section, "Quantity" section, and so forth.  When I progress through my app, if I click the Save button, at any time, it should save the current state of the Product object.

I have a `Product` object that looks like this:

```
export interface Product {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    qty: number;
}
```

My "General Info" feature page looks like this:

```
constructor(private store: Store<fromProduct.State>) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new LoadAction());
    this.product$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromProducts.getProduct));
}
```

This loads the product just fine, I see all of the values from the `product$` observable in my view.  However, I don't know how to "pass" the loaded product object to the footer component to save the state.

My footer component looks like this:

```
// Markup
<button (click)="saveProduct($event)">Save</button>

// Component
import * as productActions from '../../product/state/actions';

...

saveProduct(product: Product) {
    this.store.dispatch(new productActions.SaveProductAction(product));
}
```

I know `$event` is linked to nothing - that is what my question is.  How can I get the `Product` object from the "General Info" component into the footer component via `ngrx`?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the html? The basic problem is to pass data from child to its parent or vice versa..

Comment: @RenéWinkler, the only thing is that the "footer" component in my case is not a parent component, it is a "core" component.  It has no children but needs to act as a mechanism to trigger the event when the save button is clicked.

Comment: It sounds not very healthy to me..:-) but it would possible to solve this communication with a Subject() from rxjs.

Comment: @RenéWinkler, thanks.  I know, the whole thing kind of make me sick but unfortunately I am locked into the structure that exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your footer should not hold the save logic, since it's just a unique trigger for multiple actions.

I'd advise you to propagate the Save button click event to where your forms are.

If the form is a direct parent or sibling, then you could do it simply with `@Input()` and `@Output()`, if it's not then you can use a service to share an `Observable` between your forms and your button as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class EventService{

  private subject= new Subject<any>();

  saveButtonClicked = this.subject.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  saveButtonClick() {
    this.subject.next();
  }
}
```

Footer template:

```
<button (click)="onSaveClick()">Save</button>
```

Footer TypeScript:

```
onSaveClick() {
   this.eventService.saveButtonClick();
}
```

Your different forms:

```
this.eventService.saveButtonClicked.subscribe(res => {
   // Your save logic
});
```